# How to update Quickblox SDK in my current Project? A lot of Conflicts occuring

Tags: android, quickblox

I have my client's Project with **Quickblox SDK version 2.2.5**.
Now I want to update the **SDK with version 3.4**. I am using .jar Libraries in Android Studio Project.

I removed the 2.2.5 libraries and added 3.4 libraries successfully.**The problem is** after adding 3.4, a lot of conflicts occur in the whole Project. 

**For Example:**
 - in SDK 2.2.5 (there is QBDialog class)
 - but in SDK 3.4 (it is named with QBChatDialog)

I was thinking after adding 3.4, all the classes would be updated according to 3.4. But it is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Quick blox changes Class Names Very Often in there new Release. I suggest you to read the [Change logs](https://quickblox.com/developers/Android) at the bottom of the page first. They have made some useful changes Sdk to Help developers. For Reference check their latest [sample](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk).

And except Jars you should Use Gradle dependencies. It also mentioned in Documentation.

```
compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:3.3.1@aar'
compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:3.3.1@aar'
compile('com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.3.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Comment: Let me read the Change logs. But I just gave example of one class they changed. A lot of things have been changed. Signatures of interfaces' methods are also changed.

Is there any way to update the SDK automatically?

Comment: I suggest it would be better if you should follow the latest sample which i have linked above . It will  draw you in right direction .

Comment: But I have to use the current project. My client has already added several features. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can use the current project with Updated Sdk too with minor changes in Classes and callbacks. You see there is lots of modifications since 2.5 .

Comment: I have to change the things manually, right? There is no other way than this?

Comment: Yeah . I'm afraid so .